# opencv videocapture empty frame

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, video-capture

i'm trying to acquire image from an wireless cam with EasyCAP tuner. I can get images with any other video capture programs and matlab but in opencv i get empty frames. This code worked with my laptop webcam and with a logitec webcam. With tuner it sends me in infinite loop here beacuse of empty frame.

```
while (frame.empty())
      cap>>frame;
```

I'm using visual stuido 2010 , i have tuner on the 2nd slot(first is webcam)and my code is:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

VideoCapture cap(1);

Mat frame;
void main()
{

    char key;
    namedWindow("imag", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Sleep(1000);


cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,160);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,120);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,15);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC,CV_FOURCC('B', 'G', 'R', '3'));


    while (1)
       {

           cap>>frame;
         while (frame.empty())
              cap>>frame;

        imshow("imag",frame);
        waitKey(33);

        }
}
```

without set proprieties is the same

Comment: Did your camera start running?

Comment: this camera is working with any program except in opencv, in opencv i get empty image or zeros image(if passes the loop), with normal webcams i don't have any problem

Comment: Try to remove the four `cap.set(...)` lines.

Comment: is the same i said this at the end of my first post, is something regarding compatibility between opencv and cam's driver, STK1160 and i don't know what